# R type int / char confusion in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, types, char, int

I have a DataFrame from which I've created another DataFrame. Somewhere along the line, things got messed up, but I'm not sure where, and how to fix it.

The code worked on the first dataframe, so I assume it's some sort of type mismatch? Do I need to convert the fields back to string somehow?

```
##creating the second data frame

adat2 <- data.frame(id=character(), Title=character(), Domain=character(), lemtext1=character(), Language=character(), day=character())


##copying from the first one, whilst splitting rows into multiple rows based on lemtext

for (row in 1:nrow(adat1)) {
    splitlines <- strsplit(adat1$lemtext[row], ", |\\. |: |; ")[[1]]
    for (row2 in 1:NROW(splitlines)){
        adat2 <- add_row(adat2, id=adat1$id[row], Title=adat1$Title[row], Domain=adat1$Domain[row], lemtext1=splitlines[row2], Language=adat1$Language[row], day=adat1$day[row])
    }
}

##trying to work with the new dataframe

tokens <- space_tokenizer(adat2$`lemtext2`[which(((adat2$Domain=="index.hu") |
                                                   (adat2$Domain=="hvg.hu") | (adat1$Domain=="24.hu") | (adat1$Domain=="444.hu")) & 
                                                   (adat2$day>=as.Date("2018-10-13")) & (adat1$day<=as.Date("2019-10-13")))])
```

### getting error messages

[image: error message from R studio]

adat1 doutput:

https://www.pastiebin.com/5df253f6b79aa

Comment: We can use the code, because there is no data. Can you share `adat1`? You can do this with `dput(adat1)` of if it is big you can do `dput(head(adat1, 20))`.

Comment: hello, I've posted a doutput to https://www.pastiebin.com/5df253f6b79aa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `adat2` everything is a factor. This has to do how you created `adat2`. You need to add `stringAsFactors = FALSE` to the `data.frame()` function.

```
adat2 <- data.frame(id = character(),
                    Title = character(),
                    Domain = character(),
                    lemtext1 = character(),
                    Language = character(),
                    day = character(),
                    stringAsFactors = FALSE)
```

If you want to now what kind of columns you have. You should `str(adat2)` or per column you can use e.g. `class(adat2$id)`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Is there any way to convert adat2 to the proper format without having to run the whole code again? I'm working with a lot of data, and my loopy solution is super inefficient (it ran for 2 days, lol)

Comment: Ow, crap! You could convert each column with `adat2$id <- as.character(adat2$id)`, but I don't know if this is faster. Maybe it is an idea to look at `data.table`. This is designed for big data and doing things efficiently.

Comment: Looping is always slow, or actually something growing in a loop is slow. If you want to stay with the loop, maybe you can define the size of `adat2` before you loop.

Comment: Thanks so much! The conversion bit sounds like it should do the trick. I definitely do not want to stay with the loopy solution, but didn't really know how to do what I wanted in a more elegant manner... I'll the conversion and get back! Thanks so much once more